# function to start on arrow left click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeydown

I have this simple javascript

```
$('#about_us').on('click',function() {
    $('#slider').toggleClass('open');
});
```

All I want is to activate the funcion also by clicking the left arrow on the keyboard.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/37/)**

Add `keydown()` event and check if the `left-arrow` is clicked by `e.keyCode == 37`, try the following code :

```
$(document.body).keydown(function(e) 
{
    if(e.keyCode == 37) 
    { 
        $('#slider').toggleClass('open');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah....now I see why all the downvotes. You have the click function inside the keypress....

Comment: Use `document.body` instead of `body`, has some performance gain

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('body').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) 
    {
        $('#slider').toggleClass('open');
    }
});
```

```css
#slider {
  background:red;
  height:0px;
}
#slider.open {
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click once on this frame (to focus this body) and hit the left arrow</div>
<div id="slider">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keypress()` from jQuery: [link](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/). Key code for `left arrow` is 37.